# Storing image path string to db with Multer & Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, multer

I am trying to save the key > imageItem: value to the DB. Somehow the field is not created in the MongoDB
other key-value fields are created without issue..

I have found some similar questions here but none of them had a complete answer.
I tried a number of things such as >  itemImage:{ Type:String } etc.

**Form:**

```
<form action="/insert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title">
            <input type="text" placeholder="director" name="director">
            <input type="text" placeholder="year" name="year">
            <input type="file" placeholder="movie-image-multer" accept="image/*" name="image" >
<button type="submit">Save movie</button>
</form>
```

**in Router:**

const multer= require('multer')

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb){
    cb( null, './public/images');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb( null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
})


const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits:{
    fieldSize:1024 * 1024 * 3,
  },
})


router.post('/insert',upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  var newItem = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    director: req.body.director,
    year: req.body.year,
    image: req.file.filename
  })
  newItem.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect('insert');
      console.log(req.file.filename);
    }
    else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

**Model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var articleSchema = new Schema({
    title:  { type: String, required: true },
    director: { type: String },
    year: { type: String },
    image:{  
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
     }
});

articleSchema.set('timestamps', true);
const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema)
module.exports = Article;
```

Comment: you are saving the filename but in your model you are expecting a data buffer and a content type

Comment: field name is different in html `name="itemImage"` and in `upload.single('image')`.

Comment: @turivishal updated the issue it was image same result..

Comment: @Sebastián Espinosa I also tried > image: { type: String } no difference

Comment: have you console you are getting `console.log(req.file)` file uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. got it finaly, I used image:{ Type: String } instead of image: { type:String } in the model.
Thanks for pointing me in that direction @Sebastián Espinosa

**Updated the model as such:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var articleSchema = new Schema({
    title:  { type: String, required: true },
    director: { type: String },
    year: { type: String },
    image:{  
        type: String
     }
});

articleSchema.set('timestamps', true);
const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema)
module.exports = Article;
```